# Coordinate system conversion... without a system of equations

Tags: coordinate-systems, continuity

I'm trying to come up with a good conversion formula to go from one definition of angles in a circle to another.

In the origin system, zero is up, 90 is right, 180 is down, 270 is left.

In the target system, zero is right, -90 is down, +/- 180 is left, 90 is up.

Going backwards is easy: y=(-x+90)%360. Can anyone figure out how to go forwards in a single equation?

Comment: The exact same equation should work

Comment: @Mohit Nope, it won't. It won't ever result in a negative number, thanks to the mod.

Comment: y = -x + 90 should work without the mod 360

Comment: @Mohit It works for the first three quadrants, but for origin angles > 270, 90-x results in numbers smaller than -180.

Comment: Oh, sorry you are right. I only tried 0,90,180,270.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the origin system, zero is up, 90 is right, 180 is down, 270 is left.

Let $\,\alpha \in [0, 360)\,$ be this angle.

> In the target system, zero is right, -90 is down, +/- 180 is left, 90 is up.

Let $\,\beta\,$ be this angle, but the `+/- 180` part makes it ambiguous whether you mean the target angle to be $\beta \in (-270,90]$ vs. $\beta \in (-180,180]\,$:

- if you mean $\,\beta \in (-270,90]\,$, then just use $\,\beta = 90 - \alpha\,$;
- if you mean $\,\beta \in (-180,180]\,$, then use $\,\beta = 180 - (\alpha + 90) \;\%\; 360\,$.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to. I'm hoping there's a single equation solution, though.

Comment: @BenEtherington It *is* a single equation solution, once *you* clarify which one of the two you want the target range of $\beta$ to be. For example, if you want $\beta$ to be in $(-180,180]$ then the *only* equation you need to use is the one listed under the second case: $\,\beta = 180 - (\alpha + 90) \;\%\; 360\,$.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read too quickly. I see what you mean, yes, you nailed it! Thank you!